# Get API result when sending SparkPost email from Django?

Tags: python, django, sparkpost

If I send a message via the SparkPost python API directly, it returns a result that looks like this:

```
{'total_rejected_recipients': 0, 'total_accepted_recipients': 1, 'id': '1234567890'}
```

Django has built-in integration support for sending mail via sparkpost, if you set `MAIL_BACKEND` in `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'sparkpost.django.email_backend.SparkPostEmailBackend'
SPARKPOST_API_KEY = 'something'
```

Does Django offer a way to access the API result when using the standard Django mail methods?  (the `send_mail()` function or the `EmailMessage` class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does Django offer a way to access the API result when using the standard Django mail methods? (the send_mail() function or the EmailMessage class)

It looks like it doesn't.

[The source code](https://github.com/SparkPost/python-sparkpost/blob/7f1dc2b56e7c2bb42f1da79da3ebe884034102c7/sparkpost/django/email_backend.py#L30-L31) shows that `SparkPostEmailBackend.send_messages()` obtains a response but does not store it anywhere:

> ```python
> def send_messages(self, email_messages):
>     """
>     Send emails, returns integer representing number of successful emails
>     """
>     success = 0
>     for message in email_messages:
>         try:
>             response = self._send(SparkPostMessage(message))
>             success += response['total_accepted_recipients']
>         except Exception:
>             if not self.fail_silently:
>                 raise
>     return success
> ```

Maybe you can create your custom email backend that extends from `SparkPostEmailBackend` and overrides the `send_messages()`.